# Audio streaming with using lan storage

Tags: c#, audio, streaming

I want to stream my computers audio output over my lan storage to other devices that can access my lan storage.But I have no idea how to do it or where to start :/.I don't want code , only an idea or a method to make things go :)

Note: I dont want to stream audio with local ip adress or socket programming.

Thanks :).

Comment: Well audio streaming is usually done via `UDP` and i assume your lan storage is in an ip based network, so there is no way around ip in that case.

Comment: @MrPaulch aren't there any way to save a dump audio file and read it while being recorded from another device? Because I want to save original broadcast into archive.

Comment: Please elaborate, or better yet, draw as a graph on your post about the following: What machine is recording, what machine is distributing and what machine is accessing/reading the recording